# Should i mention OperationCanceledException in the method summary?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Given following Code

```
 public async Task<IEnumerable<AbstractPrinter>> GetAllAsync(CancellationToken ct = default)
 {
     return await _context.Set<AbstractPrinter>().AsNoTracking().ToListAsync(ct);
 }
```

A senior dev told me that i have to mention the OperationCanceledExcepion in the method summary because it can be thrown.

The following Test code proves that an OperationCanceledException will be thrown when the Task is cancelled.

```
    public async Task Cancel_GetAll_Throws()
    {
         var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<spContext>()
                        .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
                        .Options;

         using var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(new TimeSpan(100));
         using var context = new spContext(options);

         await Assert.ThrowsAsync<OperationCanceledException>(async () => await 
             context.AbstractPrinters.ToListAsync(cts.Token));
    }
```

i was looking at the ef.core docs and could not find the OperationCanceledExcepion in the summary. 
For example :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.savechangesasync?view=efcore-3.1 
doesn't mention it.

So heres my question. Should i mention the

> OperationCanceledExcepion

in the method summary?

Comment: "_everybody know's if you hand a CancelationToken there can be a OperationCancelledExcepion_" That isn't true; you could quite easily implement an async method that accepts `CancellationToken` and doesn't throw an `OperationCanceledException`.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay Your right. thanks. i edited the question based on your comment.

Comment: Even basic methods like [`NetworkStream.ReadAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.networkstream.readasync) don't document `OperationCanceledException`. Whether you *should* mention it seems opinion-based; at the same time, it seems MS itself is pretty consistently adopting the position that it's unnecessary. Certainly absence of its mention cannot be used to infer it *won't* throw, so if you had that unusual condition and you wanted developers to depend on it you'd have to document it.

Comment: @JeroenMostert  Based on your comment we decided not to mention the OperationCanceledException in the summarys because MS dosn't do it. I would accept your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you seems to misunderstand between timeout and operation cancelled.

In your Cancel_GetAll_Throws(), you didn't prove anything. Basically, what you did is. Tell an async method to cancel, then expect it to be canceled. That's all. If you don't put the code

```
using var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(/*new TimeSpan(100) REMOVE THIS */);
```

The exception won't happen.

In other words, EF doesn't throw this exception, but the task throw because you told it to throw.

Comment: Thats a good catch, but that does not answer the question. The exception does get thrown from somewhere else then. Should i mention it.

Comment: The exception was throw from the Task, not from EF. So my point is you don't need to catch that exception. Since it only happens when you ask it to happen.

Comment: If you catch it. it likes you tell the task "Please cancel the task after 100 milliseconds, I'll catch it". Then why you cancel the task on purpose?

Comment: That was only the test code. In the Production code above the token is passed in as a parameter so the user could cancel the query.

Comment: Haha, then what the point of asking this question? If your code allow to cancel, of course you need to catch it.

Comment: The question is not about catching, its about the XML Documentation aka ///summary of the method.

Comment: Yes, you need that documented since you allow that.

Comment: Microsoft does not Document the exception. So should i document it.

Comment: MS document it here (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-cancellation?view=netframework-4.8). You look into wrong documentation, it's not EF but Task.

Comment: im sorry to say you did not understand the question. if you take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.networkstream.readasync?view=netcore-3.1 a OperationCanceledException can happen but its not in the documentation under Exceptions. Microsoft seems not to document possible OperationCanceledExceptions.

Comment: And MS also did not document the `ObjectDisposedException` although it is thrown by `DbContext`.